# Location of ims sensor or ifs sensor 2002 Hyundai santa fe

Tags: hyundai, misfire, santa-fe

I have a 2002 Hyundai santa fe with the 2.7L V6 does this engine have a ifs sensor or ims sensor and if so where is it located on the engine.

The problem I am having is this, the engine will start and run well for maybe 10 seconds, then tach gets crazy and drops to nothing and engine dies.

Things I have changed, cam and crank sensor because car was throwing codes for them, I have changed the complete coil pack assembly. I have not changed plugs and wires yet.

The car is throwing these codes, misfire cylinders 2,4,6 and also random misfire multiple cylinders.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the voltage at the battery? Should be ~12.5vdc at rest without the engine running. My wife's Azera would start and run with the battery down to 10.5vdc, but the electronics would do wonky things.

Comment: Change the plugs and wires.